# Reading integers from a txt file; not coming being recorded as itegers

Tags: python, text, import

I'm reading a long list of numbers from a text file.

The numbers are:

```
12
42 45
78 30 98
12 45 12 30 ...  and so on
```

I'm loading the numbers by:

```
a = open('file', 'r')
lines = a.read()
```

When I type, lines[0] I should get the result 12, but I get 1 instead.

When I check the type of the numbers I've imported, I get:

```
<type 'str'>
```

I've tried changing the type of the number by:

```
lines = int(lines)
```

But I get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

Why is python importing strings, when they are numbers?! How do I change this...or does the data need to be imported in a different manner?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
with open('file') as f:
    array = []
    for line in f:
        array.append([int(x) for x in line.split()])
```

`a.read()` takes an argument of file size and only returns a string type

Comment: Sorry, there was an error.... w, h = [int(x) for x in f.readline().split()] # read first line
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: @Chef1075 Yes that was my fault, I had a similar code and had just copied and pasted without thinking about your variables. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Yes! The brackets! Thanks :)

Comment: Alternatively, you could do it all in one line of code with a list comprehension, like this:
`Lines = [[int(line[line.index(x)]) for x in line] for line in [line.split() for line in open('file')]]`

Answer (score 3):

The contents of the file are strings, not numbers, so you will need to include code to translate them.

If your numbers are all separated by whitespace, you can do this:

```
a = open( 'file', 'r' )
for line in a:
    numbers = [ int( x ) for x in line.split() ]
    # Do something with numbers
```

The last line breaks down into these parts:

line.split() # Break a line into N elements each separated by whitespace

int( x ) # turn the string representation into an integer

[ int( x ) for x in line.split() ] # Create a list of elements where each element is the result of int( x ) on each whitespace separated part of line.

Comment: This works, and I understand the reasoning behind it! However, i lose the structure of my data. Where before it was 1 number \n 2 numbers \n 3 numbers...it is now one long list. Still correct tho!

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
a = open('file', 'r')
lines = a.readlines()
```

That way you will get a list of th number. On the other hand, you are getting

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

because you got a newline or carrige return caracter